# How to test an exception from a future

Tags: dart, dart-async, dart-unittest

Continuing from yesterday question, how would I test that a async method throws an exception.

```
main(){
  test( "test2", () async {
    expect( await throws(), throwsException);
  });

}

Future throws () async {
  throw new FormatException("hello");
}
```

Comment: Future readers, you may be looking for `expectLater()`, scroll down...

Answer (score 21):

**Use try-catch**

The most reliable approach is to use a *try-catch* block to explicitly catch the exception and ensure the method has finished running.

```
try {
    await methodWhichThrows();
    fail("exception not thrown");
} catch (e) {
    expect(e, new isInstanceOf<...>());
    // more expect statements can go here
}
```

This approach also has the advantage that additional checks on the value of the exception can be performed.

**Expect with throwsA only works as the last statement**

Using *expect* by itself only works if it is the **last** statement in the test. There is no control over *when* the method will throw the exception, so there can be race conditions with the statements (including subsequent calls to *expect*), if they assume the exception has already been thrown.

```
expect(methodWhichThrows(), throwsA(new isInstanceOf<...>())); // unreliable unless last
```

It can be used, but you have to very careful to remember which situations it works in and which it doesn't. So it is safer to stick with the *try-catch* approach rather than using different approaches for different situations.

**Demonstration**

The following complete example demonstrates the effect of race conditions on the two approaches:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

//----------------------------------------------------------------
/// This approach to expecting exceptions is reliable.
///
Future reliableApproach(int luck) async {
  expect(await setValueAndReturnsHalf(42), equals(21));
  expect(state, equals(Evenness.isEven));

  try {
    await setValueAndReturnsHalf(3);
    fail("exception not thrown");
  } catch (e) {
    expect(e, new isInstanceOf<ArgumentError>());
  }

  // Expect value to be odd after execption is thrown.

  await shortDelay(luck); // in my experience there's no such thing called luck
  expect(state, equals(Evenness.isOdd));
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------
/// This approach to expecting exceptions is unreliable.
///
Future unreliableApproach(int luck) async {
  expect(await setValueAndReturnsHalf(42), equals(21));
  expect(state, equals(Evenness.isEven));

  expect(setValueAndReturnsHalf(3), throwsA(new isInstanceOf<ArgumentError>()));

  // Expect value to be odd after execption is thrown.

  await shortDelay(luck); // luck determines if the race condition is triggered
  expect(state, equals(Evenness.isOdd));
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------

enum Evenness { isEven, isOdd, inLimbo }

int value = 0;
Evenness state = Evenness.isEven;

/// Sets the [value] and [state].
///
/// If the [newValue] is even, [state] is set to [Evenness.isEven] and half of it
/// is returned as the Future's value.
///
/// If the [newValue] is odd, [state] is set to [Evenness.isOdd] and an exception
/// is thrown.
///
/// To simulate race conditions, this method takes 2 seconds before it starts
/// processing and 4 seconds to succeed or throw an exception. While it is
/// processing, the [state] is set to [Evenness.inLimbo].
///
Future<int> setValueAndReturnsHalf(int newValue) async {
  await shortDelay(2);

  state = Evenness.inLimbo;

  await shortDelay(2);

  value = newValue;

  if (newValue % 2 != 0) {
    state = Evenness.isOdd;
    throw new ArgumentError.value(newValue, "value", "is not an even number");
  } else {
    state = Evenness.isEven;
    return value ~/ 2;
  }
}

/// Delays used to simulate processing and race conditions.
///
Future shortDelay(int seconds) {
  var c = new Completer();
  new Timer(new Duration(seconds: seconds), () => c.complete());
  return c.future;
}

/// Examples of the reliable and unreliable approaches.
///
void main() {
  test("Correct operation when exception is not thrown", () async {
    expect(await setValueAndReturnsHalf(42), equals(21));
    expect(value, equals(42));
  });

  group("Reliable approach:", () {
    test("works when there is bad luck", () async {
      // 1 second = bad luck, future returning function not started processing yet
      await reliableApproach(1);
    });

    test("works when there is more bad luck", () async {
      // 3 second = bad luck, future returning function still processing
      await reliableApproach(3);
    });

    test("works when there is good luck", () async {
      // 5 seconds = good luck, future returning function definitely finished
      await reliableApproach(5);
    });
  });

  group("Unreliable approach:", () {
    test("race condition encountered by bad luck", () async {
      // 1 second = bad luck, future returning function not started processing yet
      await unreliableApproach(1);
    });

    test("race condition encountered by more bad luck", () async {
      // 3 second = bad luck, future returning function still processing
      await unreliableApproach(3);
    });

    test("race condition avoided by good luck", () async {
      // 5 seconds = good luck, future returning function definitely finished
      await unreliableApproach(5);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You can also use `await expectLater(..., throwsA(...))`. This allows awaiting the async expectation, avoiding the problem of not knowing when the operation is finished.

Answer (score 13):

This way it works:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  test( "test2", ()  { // with or without `async`
    expect(throws(), throwsA(const TypeMatcher<FormatException>()));
  });
}

Future throws () async {
  throw new FormatException("hello");
}
```

Basically just remove `await`. The test framework can deal with futures no matter if they succeed or fail.

Comment: I think expectAsync would be helpful here.

Comment: Why do you think? Shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Because "throws()" method is async.

Comment: It would just make it more complicated. ExpectAsync is to check whether some async code got executed. Checking for an exception is as simple as in my answer.

Comment: to have more example on this I have added one answer with exceptAsync

Answer (score 7):

The [official document](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_api/latest/expect/throwsA.html) have good examples by using `expectLater` with `throwsA` for that as following examples.

```dart
void functionThatThrows() => throw SomeException();

void functionWithArgument(bool shouldThrow) {
  if (shouldThrow) {
    throw SomeException();
  }
}

Future<void> asyncFunctionThatThrows() async => throw SomeException();

expect(functionThatThrows, throwsA(isA<SomeException>()));

expect(() => functionWithArgument(true), throwsA(isA<SomeException>()));

var future = asyncFunctionThatThrows();
await expectLater(future, throwsA(isA<SomeException>()));

await expectLater(
    asyncFunctionThatThrows, throwsA(isA<SomeException>()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and shortest answer is:

```dart
expect(throws(), throwsException)
```

To test exception/error type:

```dart
expect(throws(), throwsA(predicate((e) => e is MyException)));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to test errors coming from Future. Gunter's answer will work if "throws without async" method is throwing some exception. Below sample will handle exception coming from future methods.

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
    test("test with Zone", () {
        runZoned(() {
            throws();
        }, onError: expectAsync((e, s) {
            expect(e, new isInstanceOf<FormatException>());
        }));
    });

    test('test with future catch error', () {
        throws().catchError(expectAsync((e) {
            expect(e, new isInstanceOf<FormatException>());
        }));
    });
}

Future throws() async{
    Completer completer = new Completer();
    completer.complete(new Future(() => throw new FormatException("hello")));
    return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: My version would work the same with your `throws()` method.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, these are few additional ways to do it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer's answer is  simpler and more concise.

Answer (score 0):

After too many tries and errors I found that this one works as expected:

```dart
test('fetch SHOULD throw exception WHEN api fail with exception', () {
  when(clientMock.get(uri)).thenAnswer((_) async => throw Exception());
  expect(() => sut.fetch(), throwsA(isInstanceOf < Exception > ()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't satisfied with any of the other answers; too verbose.

So the short version is:

```dart
test('ArgumentError is thrown when throwIt is true', () {
   expectLater(() => myAsyncFunctionThatTakesAnArgument(throwIt: true), throwsA(isA<ArgumentError>()));
});
```